# PROC : Regarding proc Executable size difference

Tags: c, unix, binary, executable, proc

2 years back , I have compiled the proc test.pc and create the executbale "test" .

Now same proc program I have compiled , 
but executable size is different compare to previous one(i didn't change the proc code).

Why it is happend or anything I have missed while compiling?

Please let me know 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the version of gcc is different.